# Haskell List Monad — generalize by parameter

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads

Let's imagine a population (of humans). Each human has things, that have length (left arm, right arm, left leg, right leg). Each human has things, that may have width (chest, waist). There are much more parameters that a human may have.

All measurement types are

```
allMeasurementTypes = [Width, Length, Diameter, Weight] -- and similar things.
```

For statistics I want to get for all population all possible pairs of measurements.

Something like that:

```
Pair1_LeftLeg Pair1_Waist Pair2_LeftLeg Pair2_Chest Pair3_RightLeg Pair3_Waist...
102           70          102           90          101            70         ...
115           60          115           85          116            60         ...
...           ...         ...           ...         ...            ...        ...
```

Don't tell me, that there are duplications here. I know. But it is easier for me to have it like that to process further in statistical applications.

So I construct this in the following way

```
allMeasurements :: [Human] -> Seq (Int, [(String, [Double])])
allMeasurements population = mapWithIndex (,) measures
  where
    measures = do
      mTypes <- fromList $ choose allMeasurementTypes 2
      rec1 <- recordsForPeople population $ head mTypes
      rec2 <- recordsForPeople population $ mTypes !! 1
      return [rec1, rec2]
```

And now I explain it line by line.

```
allMeasurements :: [Human] -> Seq (Int, [(String, [Double])])
```

Here `Int` is the number of the pair. If it is `Pair1`, then `String` would be `"LeftLeg"` and then `"Waist"`. `[Double]` is the array of values of each measurement on *all population.*

```
allMeasurements population = mapWithIndex (,) measures
  where
    measures = do
      mTypes <- fromList $ choose allMeasurementTypes 2
```

This iterates through all possible pairs of measurement types. `choose` gets all possible pairs like `[Width, Length]`, `[Width, Diameter]`...

```
      rec1 <- recordsForPeople population $ head mTypes
```

Assuming, that first mType is `Length`, `rec1` iterates through all possible lengths. `rec1` iterates through `("LeftLeg", [102, 115, ...])`, `("RightLeg", [101, 116, ...])`...

```
      rec2 <- recordsForPeople population $ mTypes !! 1
```

Assuming, that second mType is `Width`, `rec2` iterates through all possible widths. `rec2` iterates through `("Waist", [70, 60, ...])`, `("Chest", [90, 85, ...])`...

```
      return [rec1, rec2]
```

And finally I collect together all everything. It gives full `Seq` of all possible pairs of individual measurements for all population. `mapWithIndex` above just runs through this full list and injects actual `Int` number of pair inside. I chose `Seq` actually only because it has this `mapWithIndex`. Then it all goes out for rendering to `csv` or `json`.

Maybe I might do it better and smarter. Uff.

Here comes the real question.

Besides table of pairs, I also want to generate table of trinities.

```
allTriMeasurements :: [Human] -> Seq (Int, [(String, [Double])])
allTriMeasurements population = mapWithIndex (,) measures
  where
    measures = do
      mTypes <- fromList $ choose allMeasurementTypes 3
      rec1 <- recordsForPeople population $ head mTypes
      rec2 <- recordsForPeople population $ mTypes !! 1
      rec3 <- recordsForPeople population $ mTypes !! 2
      return [rec1, rec2, rec3]
```

Is it anyhow possible to generalize these two functions `allMeasurements` and `allTriMeasurements` by parameter `n`, defining if it is 2 for pairs or 3 for trinities.

I already dropped the ideas about `fmap` and similar, because here for (monadic) list comprehension all `rec_i <- ...` should go one after another. And any kind of `doSomething <$> [0 .. (n-1)]` breaks the structure.

It is pretty possible, that I did it all wrong. If anyone besides me is able to understand, what is going on here, I would greatly appreciate any ideas. As it seems to me the ugliest place in my code.

Comment: In both cases, the `recordsForPeople` lines can be written `mapM (recordsForPeople population) mTypes`. All that is left then is to generalize the integer passed to `choose`. `measures` becomes quite simply `fromList (choose allMeasurementTypes k) >>= mapM (recordsForPeople population)`, where `k` is a parameter passed to `allMeasurements`.

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly, what I was missing in my understanding. I overlooked this superpower of `mapM`.

Answer (score 1):

```
allMeasurements :: Int -> [Human] -> Seq (Int, [(String, [Double])])
allMeasurements k population = mapWithIndex (,) measures
  where
    measures = mapM (recordsForPeople population) =<< fromList (choose allMeasurementTypes k)
```

Soo easy. I just overlooked `mapM` superpower.